# How to fix browser displaying horizontal scroll after inserting web part list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have this web part list of named resources that displaying 5 column 500px fixed width, it has vertical scroll in it.

it is in table form  and

// I tried to edit the css by resizing both table and td somehow it works but the horizontal scroll in the screen doesn't disappear

// I also tried to adjust width to fit zone and edit the css but the same it doesn't work the horizontal scroll is still there.

Q> is there is way to fix displaying the web part list without affecting the browser?
[image: screenshot of browser and web part list]

[image: html]
I've been trying to use overflow:hidden on table and td but its just the same

NOTE:I'tried to put in left column and somehow it fix but when i put it in the right column the browser horizontal starting to show again.

Comment: Hello jayllopy. Can you add please your script / css to the question?

Comment: hello @SteffPoint i've tried to use overflow, max-width and width to fix this somehow no luck, the table resize but the screen horizontal scroll doesnt disappear.